# Evaluate the integral F • dr along C

Tags: surface-integrals, stokes-theorem, greens-theorem

Evaluate the integral $F • dr$ along $C$ where $F$ is the vector function $F(x,y, z) = < -y^2, x, z^2 >$  and $C$ is the curve of the intersection of the plane $y + z = 2$ and  the cylinder $x^2 + y^2 =1$. Orient C counter clockwise when viewed from above.

My intuition tells me this curve $C$ is an ellipse. And I can use Stokes theorem to evaluate the integral. But if I did not have stokes theorem and I wanted to compute the integral directly, how would I parametrize the curve.

Comment: As a hint in the right direction, how would you parameterize the curve $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: I'd use cylindrical coordinates, where $r=1$ and $z=2-y=2-\sin(\theta)$

Answer (score 1):

Parametrize as follows:
\begin{cases}
x=\cos t\\
y=\sin t\\
z= 2-y = 2-\sin t
\end{cases}
with $0\le t \le 2\pi$. Then,
$$
\int_C \vec{F}\cdot d\vec{r} = \int_0^{2\pi}\pmatrix{-\sin^2 t \\ \cos t \\(2-\sin t)^2}\cdot \pmatrix{-\sin t \\ \cos t \\ -\cos t}\; dt=\int_0^{2\pi}\sin^3t +\cos^2 t-\cos t(2-\sin t)^2 \; dt = \;...
$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.** Use the paratmetrization $x=\cos \theta$ and $y=\sin \theta.$ Sketch a diagram.